# How to add new row in a MultiIndex dataframe based on two or more conditions based on the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

I am trying to add new row into my MultiIndex dataframe based on more than one condition.

The following code is how I setup the initial dataframe that I want to operate on (not the real one, but good enough to illustrate the problem that I am having...):

```py
def mklbl(prefix, n):
    return ["%s%s" % (prefix, i) for i in range(n)]

----


    miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A', 3),
                                           mklbl('B', 4),
                                           ], names=['A','B'])

    micolumns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'foo'), ('a', 'bar'),
                                           ('b', 'foo'), ('b', 'bah')],
                                           names=['lvl0', 'lvl1'])


    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=len(miindex) * len(micolumns))
                        .reshape((len(miindex), len(micolumns))),
                         index=miindex,
                         columns=micolumns).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)                         

    df = df.drop([('A2','B2'),('A2','B3')])
```

Here is the starting `df`:

```
lvl0    a       b    
lvl1  bar foo bah foo
A  B                 
A0 B0  38  16   1  31
   B1  49  12  97  73
   B2  76  26  17  34
   B3   8  55   6  80
A1 B0  40  94  57   0
   B1  21  23  45  78
   B2  36  31  89  18
   B3  46  31  57  94
A2 B0  46  98  62  97
   B1  89  26  93  95
```

The question is: How do I create a new index such that in every `A` that has `B2` and `B3` entries, if `B3 < B2` then `B4 = B3 / B2` else `B4 = 0`;

I expect the result will be like this:

```
lvl0    a       b    
lvl1  bar foo bah foo
A  B                 
A0 B0  38       16   1          31
   B1  49       12  97          73
   B2  76       26  17          34
   B3   8       55   6          80
   B4  0.105     0  0.352        0
A1 B0  40       94  57           0
   B1  21       23  45          78
   B2  36       31  89          18
   B3  46       31  57          94
   B4   0        0  0.640        0
A2 B0  46       98  62          97
   B1  89       26  93          95
```

This is very difficult for me to do. I have tried do it on my own for the whole day using `pd.IndexSlice`, `get_level_values`, `boolean indexer` and what not but to no avail. It's so frustrating.

Thank you for any help out there.

Comment: What is `mklbl` function?

Comment: I have added `mklbl` function in the post above. Sorry for missing this.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to transform the data so you can do these operations on columns rather than rows:

```
df = df.T.stack('A')
```

Then you can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to suit your conditions:

```
df['B4'] = np.where(df.B3 < df.B2, df.B3 / df.B2, 0)
```

The previous line will leave `0` values where `B2` or `B3` is `nan`.  To fix that:

```
df['B4'] = np.where(df.B3.isnull() | df.B2.isnull(), np.nan, df.B4)
```

Now you can transform back:

```
df = df.stack('B').unstack(['lvl0', 'lvl1'])
```

---

In one set:

```
df = df.T.stack('A')
df['B4'] = np.where(df.B3 < df.B2, df.B3 / df.B2, 0)
df['B4'] = np.where(df.B3.isnull() | df.B2.isnull(), np.nan, df.B4)
df = df.stack('B').unstack(['lvl0', 'lvl1'])
```

---

With the following dataframe:

```
lvl0    a       b
lvl1  bar foo bah foo
A  B
A0 B0  59  41  50  82
   B1  77   7  15  77
   B2  91  57  44  98
   B3  74  54  52  88
A1 B0  35  47  68   4
   B1  93  93  20  93
   B2  68  76  67  29
   B3   9  50  25   3
A2 B0   7  59  69  74
   B1  19  34  40  32
```

This produces:

```
lvl0           a                     b
lvl1         bar        foo        bah        foo
A  B
A0 B0  59.000000  41.000000  50.000000  82.000000
   B1  77.000000   7.000000  15.000000  77.000000
   B2  91.000000  57.000000  44.000000  98.000000
   B3  74.000000  54.000000  52.000000  88.000000
   B4   0.813187   0.947368   0.000000   0.897959
A1 B0  35.000000  47.000000  68.000000   4.000000
   B1  93.000000  93.000000  20.000000  93.000000
   B2  68.000000  76.000000  67.000000  29.000000
   B3   9.000000  50.000000  25.000000   3.000000
   B4   0.132353   0.657895   0.373134   0.103448
A2 B0   7.000000  59.000000  69.000000  74.000000
   B1  19.000000  34.000000  40.000000  32.000000
```

Comment: It works, thanks, but the `stack` and `unstack` is making me lose my original order of my A and B. In this example, it just so happen that the index are created in ascending order. Do you know how to maintain the order?

Answer (score 0):

`groupby(level=...)` could help here by splitting the dataframe according to the `A` level of the multi-index. From there, it is enough to search whether `B2` and `B3` both exist and if yes compute the new row.

It will be necessary to sort according to the index in order to put the new rows at their correct place. Code could be:

```
for A, g in df.index.to_frame().groupby(level='A'):
    if ((A, 'B2') in g.index) and ((A, 'B3') in g.index):
        df.loc[(A, 'B4'), :] = np.where(
            df.loc[(A, 'B3')]<df.loc[(A, 'B2')],
            df.loc[(A, 'B3')] / df.loc[(A, 'B2')],
            0)

df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```